# How do you perform the chase test?

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory, relations

Trying to follow the chase algorithm as I understand it,

1. If two rows agree in the left side of a functional dependency (FD for brevity), make
   their right sides agree too.
2. Always replace a subscripted symbol by the
   corresponding unsubscripted one, if possible.
3. If we ever get an unsubscripted row, we know
   any tuple in the project-join is in the original
   (the join is lossless).
4. Otherwise, the final tableau is a counter
   example

So I tried to perform the chase algorithm on an example schema. Given `R (A, B, C, D, E)` decomposed into relations `{A, B, C}`, `{B, C, D}`, `{A, C, E}` and FDs, `A → D`, `CD → E` and `E → D`

Beginning the chase test

```
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----+
| a   | b   | c | d   | e   |
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----+
| a   | b   | c | d_1 | e_1 |
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----+
| a_2 | b   | c | d   | e_2 |
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----+
| a   | b_3 | c | d_3 | e   |
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----+
```

And ending

```
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----+
| a   | b   | c | d   | e   |
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----+
| a   | b   | c | d_1 | e   |
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----+
| a_2 | b   | c | d   | e_2 |
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----+
| a   | b_3 | c | d_1 | e   |
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----+
```

So the final tableau is a counter example and this isn't lossless.

Comment: You are correct, the decomposition is not lossless.

Comment: Seems that given FDs are not sufficient.